# Python - schedule library

Tags: python, schedule

i'm currently facing an issue with my python code which presents randomly. Basically i have written two scripts which need to run each day at the same time:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    schedule.every().day.at("23:15").do(job)
    schedule.every().day.at("23:25").do(avvia_metatraders)
 
while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The issue is that sometimes they are executed without any issu, while other times like the past night the script waits in standby until i press any key on the keyboard. In other words, after i launch it it waits for the time of the day to execute but it doesn't execute anything until a press a random key on my keyboard.

Did somebody have the same experience?

To add to this, the same happens when i'm executing the code. Some parts of it get stuck until i press a random key. Is there any way to debug these issues?

Thanks

Comment: Does your running scripts have `inputs` or any code that requires keyboard interactions?

Comment: No, it should work flawlessly